# It is fine to end a sentence with a comparative adjective?

Tags: adjectives, comparison

It is fine to end a sentence with a *comparative adjective*? 
For example: `It's better. It's faster. She's nicer.` Or it's necessary to the sentence with a full comparison such as: It's better **than it**. This is faster **than the second**. She's nicer **than her sister**.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comparing 2 things and the second thing is not understood, *than X* should be used.

Sometimes you are comparing the current state of something with its own previous state.  *Than* is usually omitted since typically it’s obvious what the *than X* is.

> I fixed the engine and now the car runs better.

Of course if you want to be extra clear, you can still use *than X.*

> I fixed the engine and now it runs better than it did before.